# Excel VBA FileSystemObject GetFolder

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I would like to be able to get file information on a list of paths that I enter into a range of cells. I also don't want to get all the Subfolders either. I have this code that works great using 1 folder path.

```
Sub Get_Information()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File

Dim last_row As Integer

sh.Rows(1).Font.Size = 18

Set fo = fso.GetFolder(sh.Range("H1").Value)

For Each f In fo.Files
    last_row = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    sh.Range("A" & last_row).Value = f.Name
    sh.Range("B" & last_row).Value = f.Type
    sh.Range("C" & last_row).Value = f.Size / 1024
    sh.Range("D" & last_row).Value = f.DateLastModified

Next

MsgBox ("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all paths in one cell, you could split the string in that cell and then loop 
with an array

```
Sub Get_Information()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File
Dim pathArray as Variant
Dim SplitString as String    

Dim last_row As Integer

sh.Rows(1).Font.Size = 18

SplitString = sh.Range("H1").Value
pathArray = Split(SplitString, ";") 'change to whatever seperator you are using

For each pth in pathArray

    Set fo = fso.GetFolder(pth)

    For Each f In fo.Files
        last_row = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        sh.Range("A" & last_row).Value = f.Name
        sh.Range("B" & last_row).Value = f.Type
        sh.Range("C" & last_row).Value = f.Size / 1024
        sh.Range("D" & last_row).Value = f.DateLastModified

    Next f

Next pth
MsgBox ("Done")
```

**EDIT**

If you want to loop through a range of cells instead:

```
Sub Get_Information()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File
Dim c as Range

Dim last_row As Integer

sh.Rows(1).Font.Size = 18

For each pth in sh.Range("H1:H" & last_row) 'Edit range
  If not pth.value = ""
    Set fo = fso.GetFolder(c.Value)

    For Each f In fo.Files
        last_row = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        sh.Range("A" & last_row).Value = f.Name
        sh.Range("B" & last_row).Value = f.Type
        sh.Range("C" & last_row).Value = f.Size / 1024
        sh.Range("D" & last_row).Value = f.DateLastModified

    Next f

  End If
Next pth
MsgBox ("Done")
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. Each path will be in a separate cell within a column

Comment: Edited my answer to accomodate your preferences

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for adjusting your code. I'm just getting an error `c.Value = <Object or With block not set>` at the line `Set fo = fso.GetFolder(c.Value)`